# Lost my reference to Microsoft.InteropFormTools in a VB.NET 2008 project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, com-interop

I've got an older VB.NET 2008 project, which uses Crystal Reports.  In order to access the .rpt files I used Microsoft.InteropFormTools assembly.  This has worked OK for a number of years.  What this does is allows the user to specify what amounts to parameters to the reports in the Crystal Reports, and then click a button and out prints the report.  (The user is not interested in previewing the report, so it prints directly to the printer, using Crystal.)  The one problem, which I've never been able to figure out, is that sometimes (how, and under what circumstances I don't know, because I can reliably reproduce the error) loading the Crystal Report will cause an error flag to come up.  Next Crystal will insist that the user enter parameters to the report before it previews them.  OF course the users don't know what's going on, so what we've done in the past is just have the user start it over again, and Crystal normally is happy and sends the report to the printer.

However, we've got new users coming on board to do this, and they're not as forgiving. When I wrote this app 4 years ago, I let the CPU be “Any CPU”.  I'm wondering if that could be the root of my problems with these Crystal reports not coming out.  So, I've gotten into the project, and changed it from “Any CPU” to “x86”, which really is more appropriate, especially since our old version of Crystal is 32-bit.  However, now that I've done that I've got a new error message popping up.  Visual Studio 2008 is telling me that, “The system cannot find the reference specified”.  In this case the missing reference is Microsoft.InteropFormTools.  No other changes have happened to this application in 3 years, besides my changing the project configuration from “Any CPU” to “x86”.  Could that be what's causing it to not be able to find the path to Microsoft.InteropFormTools?